# Sqoop import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_MAPS error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am using hadoop2.6.0 ,hive1.2.1 and sqoop 1.4.6. while importing emp table from mysql to hive, it's copy table data into /user/hive/warehouse/emp, But It throws the following error as,

I am using the command:

```
 sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password hadoop --table emp -m 1 --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/



[main] mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1473826602802_0002

 2016-09-13 22:32:20,943 INFO [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_1473826602802_0002 running in uber mode : false
 2016-09-13 22:32:21,005 INFO [main] mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0% 

2016-09-13 22:32:59,525 INFO [main] mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%

 2016-09-13 22:33:01,727 INFO [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_1473826602802_0002 completed successfully

 **2016-09-13 22:33:03,190 ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_MAPS**
```

How to solve this error.Is there any settings required for this.suggest me.